# Setting TimeToLive on an item from an Azure Function (Node.JS)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure Function with an output binding to Azure Cosmos DB for saving items. I'm trying to set TimeToLive on an Item Level (I know that TTL must be on for the container to work). On the container level, TTL is enabled to -1 via the portal. Is there a way to set TTL via the OutputBinding for each element via a property?

My binding:

```json
{
  "type": "cosmosDB",
  "direction": "out",
  "name": "outputDocument",
  "databaseName": "myDatabase",
  "collectionName": "myCollection",
  "createIfNotExists": true,
  "PartitionKey": "/customerId",
  "defaultTtl": -1, //doesn't work and has to be set via Azure Portal
  "connectionStringSetting": "CosmosDbConnectionString"
}
```

And of course the index.ts part where I'm writing data to Cosmos DB:

```js
const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, eventGridEvent: EventGridEvent<DTO>): Promise<void> {
    context.bindings.outputDocument = JSON.stringify(eventGridEvent.data);
}
export default HttpTrigger;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item needs to have a "ttl" property added to it.

Assuming your `eventGridEvent.data` contains the complete document you are saving, you could do:

```
var item = eventGridEvent.data;
item["ttl"] = 60; // 60 seconds
context.bindings.outputDocument = JSON.stringify(item);
```

Comment: Thank you!
Is there a way to set defaultTimeToLive in the function.json as well?
So if the DB doesn't exist and get's created TTL is set to on?
Doesn't work in the example above...

Comment: Sadly no, there is no property you can set so the collection is created with TTL enabled from the binding. You can see the available configuration options here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-output?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-javascript#configuration